# Scala - Play downloads .html file instead of being opening it

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to open an HTML file in the browser. All documentation/answers online suggest that the following is what I should have in my routes file:

```
GET   /test controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/html", file="test.html")
```

Where `test.html` is located in `public/html`. However, when I go to `/test`, `test.html` is downloaded when I want it to just open in the browser (which I think is the expected behaviour of the `.at` function).

This has only started happening recently and no changes have been made to routes file or html file.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve an HTML file, you should have a Result. Results are defined within the controllers. For example:

`def example = Action {OK(views.html.myhtml)}`

Looks for the file `myhtml.scala.html` within the `views` folder. And here the controller method serves the result `ok` (http status 200) with that html file.

The asset folder is for ... well asset files which then can be used within the webpages: javascript/css/image files.